# What is probability of a heart of coin or a club?

Tags: probability

The situation is a coin tossed and a card pulled from normal deck. 
My sample space: 2 faces of coin X 52 card = 104. 
1 head can go with 13 clubs. So my probability  is 13/104.
But the book's answer is 5/8. Hope to hear your own ideas about this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that you're looking for the probability of Heads ($H$) *or* a Clubs ($C$). (One, or the other, or both).

If it was the probability of $H$ *and* $C$ you'd have done it perfectly.

This means the probability you want is $P(H, \text{not }C) + P(C, \text{not }H) + P(\text{Both})$.

Since the outcomes are independent you can work out the "and" probability by multiplying them together, then add those resulting probabilities to get the "or". The working follows:

$$P(H) = \frac{1}{2}, P(C) = \frac{1}{4} =\frac{13}{52}.$$

So $P(\text{Both}) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{8}, P(H, \text{not }C) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{8}$. $P(C, \text{not }H) = \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{8}$.

The total is therefore $\frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{8} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{5}{8}$.

Note: you can also look at it a different way, the probability of a Heads is $\frac{1}{2}$, no matter what happens with the cards. So all you have left to work out is the probability of getting a Clubs and a Tails, which is $\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{8}$. So the total probability again is $\frac{5}{8}$.

Let me know if you want me to explain it slightly differently, try having a flick through something like this https://www.bbc.com/bitesize/guides/zsrq6yc/revision/7 as well

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks for your enthusiasm.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that the coin is heads or a club is chosen. If so the probably will be:

$P_{\text{heads}}+P_{\text{clubs}}-P_{\text{heads and a club}}$.

This will be equal to:

$\frac 12+\frac 14-\frac 18=\frac 58$

I believe you may have misread it as $P_{\text{heads and a club}}$ which is equal to $\frac 18$ or $\frac {13}{104}$ as you wrote.

Comment: Thanks! I got it.

Comment: @Willy In general if you find an answer helpful, you should upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry, i can not upvote more than 1 at the same time.